# Is there a more sophisticated way of saying, "I would love to talk about that!"?

Tags: synonyms

Recently, mentioned a hobby as I introduced myself in an online class, and someone responded by saying they had the same hobby.

The only reply I can think of is "I would love to talk about that!"

Is there another, more elegant, way of saying that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The simplest sentence would be: Let's talk!

Comment: Let's compare notes! [That 3-word sentence implies you want to talk about the hobby you have in common. If, say, your shared hobby is stamp collecting, you could expand the sentence by saying, "Let's compare notes on our common interest in stamp collecting."

Answer (score 1):

Just say 'tell me more' or 'let's discuss!'